# Node.js (Express JS 3.x with Socket.io together)

Tags: session, socket.io, express

I need to share session between sockets and express js.
I've tried to make this example work: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/ without success. Web browser return

> GET localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1354005884872 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

on session start. I get server side error:

> warn  - handshake error Error

**Server side script:**

```
var express = require('express')
  , util = require('util')
  , connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')
  , parseCookie = connect.utils.parseCookie
  , MemoryStore = connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore
  , store;

  var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  var connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')
  , util = require('util')
  , cookie = require('cookie')
  , parseCookie = cookie.parse
  , MemoryStore = connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore
  , store;

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
      secret: 'secret'
    , key: 'express.sid'
    , store: store = new MemoryStore()
    }));
    app.use(function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello, your session id is ' + req.sessionID);
    });
});

io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
  if (!data.headers.cookie) 
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);

  data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
  data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];

  store.load(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
    if (err || !session) return accept('Error', false);

    data.session = session;
    return accept(null, true);
  });
}).sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var sess = socket.handshake.session;
  socket.log.info(
      'a socket with sessionID'
    , socket.handshake.sessionID
    , 'connected'
  );
  socket.on('set value', function (val) {
    sess.reload(function () {
      sess.value = val;
      sess.touch().save();
    });
  });
});

app.use(count);

// custom middleware
function count(req, res) {
  req.session.count = req.session.count || 0;
  var n = req.session.count++;
  res.send('viewed ' + n + ' times\n');
}

server.listen(8000);
```

**Client side script:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js" %>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

socket.io v0.9.11, express.js v3.0.3, connect v2.7.0, cookie v0.0.5

I wish you can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801027/since-connect-doesnt-use-the-parsecookie-method-anymore-how-can-we-get-session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801027/since-connect-doesnt-use-the-parsecookie-method-anymore-how-can-we-get-session)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a project that might help simplify everything for you. Express.io combines express and socket.io and includes a bunch of easy to get working examples:
https://github.com/techpines/express.io

I've only toyed with it a little myself, but it looked promising. Hope this helps.